# PWA builder, ios xcode files are not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, progressive-web-apps

I was trying to create APK and iOS xcode files from a URL via pwabuilder.com. The URL scored 87/100, but when I click "Build your PWA" button I can't see the dowload for ios xcode file package. Only Android, Samsung store and Windows are there. Is there any recent changes?